# Фиксированное количество записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно чтобы таблица при достижении 5000 записей - не увеличивалась в размерах, а при добавлении новых записей удалялось соответствующие количество самых первых записей.
Как я понимаю нужно смотреть в сторону триггеров.

Конечно можно добавить проверку к-ва записей по крону, и если выше 5000 - удалять данные, но хотелось бы сделать более красиво.

Возможно ли это реализовать средствами sql ?

Comment: средствами SQL нельзя, потому что триггер это не SQL, это расширения конкретных СУБД. А триггера MySQL не позволяют триггеру модифицировать таблицу для которой он создан

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напрямую триггером не получится, т.к. в mysql триггер не может изменять таблицу, для которой вызван. Да и `count` постоянно дёргать не очень интересная идея.

`cron` или нативный [`event scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) в mysql вполне нормальное решение.

Или извращаться, например всю запись отправить в отдельную таблицу `engine=blackhole`, а `before insert` триггером переписывать в нужную таблицу.

Или изначально вставить в таблицу 5000 записей, повесить триггер на `before insert` с генерированием пользовательской ошибки. И всегда использовать `update` с поиском самой старой записи.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так?

```
 DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 5000 ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

Comment: Выбрать первые 5000 записей с произвольной сортировкой, а остальные удалить. Гениальное решение!

Comment: Поправил, не стой стороны брал топ, @Anton Shchyrov А уточните, почему вы считаете, что сортировка произвольна?

Comment: @Venta потому, что если не указан параметр `ORDER BY`, то, согласно стандарту SQL, сервер может вытягивать записи в произвольном порядке. Скажем, в порядке физического расположения записей на диске

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Спасибо, до это это считал, что `TOP` занимается сортировкой по умолчанию.

Comment: @Venta `TOP` возвращает первые n записей из набора. Сортировкой набора он не занимается и не должен, т.к. набор может формироваться совершенно произвольным образом

Comment: Напомню, что речь о `mysql`. Никакого `select top` в `mysql` нет вообще. И `delete` по подзапросу к этой же таблице вам `mysql` тривиальными способами сделать не даст.

Comment: Да, но в вопросе звучало `Возможно ли это реализовать средствами sql ?`